# Tensorflow crashes with no stack trace while feeding large numpy arrays when using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have inputs (shape: (None, 416, 416, 3)) and targets (shape: (None, 13, 13, 5, 19)) that I'm trying to zip together into a data pipeline. Both inputs and targets are placeholders so I have been feeding in the numpy arrays consisting of my data in the sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict = {inputs: _inputs, targets: _targets}) function. I am using an initializable iterator and my dataset consists of ~10000 entries. However, when I run my code, it stops prematurely on the sess.run method below with zero stack trace. Running %ERRORLEVEL% gives me -1073741819. What does this error level mean?

I have tried slicing my data into smaller numpy arrays and calling sess.run every time I exhaust an array. This approach works, but has significant hang time every time sess.run is called. This approach makes every 10 epochs take roughly 5 minutes longer than just ditching tf.data and using feed dict exclusively. I've also looked into system ram while the program is running and it never exceeds 40%. In addition, I tried setting the parameter shuf_buf_size to 100 (even smaller than the slices above).

Code I used to construct the pipeline

```py
def dataset(inputs, targets, shuf_buf_size, batch_size, prefetch_buf_size):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        in_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
        tar_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(targets)
        zipped = tf.data.Dataset.zip((in_dataset, tar_dataset))
        return zipped.shuffle(shuf_buf_size).batch(batch_size).prefetch(prefetch_buf_size)
```

Code in session

```py
#training
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        if os.path.isfile(ckpt_path + '.index'):
            saver = blocks['saver']
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt_path)
        else:
            initializer.run()
            print('Initialized all variables')

        ...
        sess.run(iterator.initializer,
                        feed_dict = {inputs: _inputs,
                                    targets: _targets})
        ...
```

Memory shouldn't be a problem since I was able to load in the numpy arrays without problem. However, I know the problem is related to memory as slicing my numpy arrays before feeding them in worked.

Comment: Not sure about correct solutions here, but you can 1) try to convert your dataset to TFRecord format and use that 2) remove prefetching as another experiment

Comment: @y.selivonchyk I admittingly was too lazy to convert it to TFRecord but I just did it and it worked perfectly. I'm still confused why my original method didn't work.